# Снова о полканах

Tags: этимология

Мной однажды уже задавался вопрос о том, что означает расхожая кличка собак Полкан. Но вот еще очень интересует, почему этим же словом называется дымковская игрушка в виде кентавра?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так вроде вам ещё там и ответили, что кентавр как раз и назывался на Руси полканом. 
Тут скорее надо задавать ворос, почему полкан стал собакой. Тут просто произошло смешение двух сказочных животных. Отечественного получеловека-полупса и заморского получеловека-полуконя. Тем более, что и тот и другой были символом храброго воина.
Точно также, кстати, наша земноводная русалка (птица с девичьей головой) вдруг стала "ненашей" морской девой.